# powershell Get-Content -raw alternative for PS Version 2

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

For later powershell versions I can use the following with no issue:

```
$contents = Get-Content $path -raw
if ($contents -match $regex) {
    $result = $matches[0]
}
```

But in powershell version 2, there's no -raw switch for Get-Content, but then without the -raw switch, the regex matching step always fails; $matches appear to be $null.

I am not sure of the inner workings of this "raw" parameter does, because Microsoft has provided a rather pathetic description of it on the respective documentation page, so I am not sure how to work around it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Get-Content -Raw` ignores newline characters and reads the contents of the file as one string.

Here are two methods that simulate the PowerShell 3.0+ `-Raw` functionality in PowerShell 2.0:

```
$contents = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($path)

if ($contents -match $regex) {
    $result = $matches[0]
}
```

Or:

```
$contents = Get-Content -Path $path | Out-String

if ($contents -match $regex) {
    $result = $matches[0]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to @HAL9256, you can just join the strings together:

```
[string]$contents = @(Get-Content -Path $path) -join [Environment]::NewLine
```

Otherwise `Get-Content` returns an array of strings.

```
if ($contents -match $regex)
{
    $result = $matches[0]
}
```